# How to find scaled point before scale?

Tags: java, android, animation, math, geometry

I have a view and animation for that. I scaled up this view on `3X` and `3Y`.

**pivotX and pivotY -> center of View**

And i want to find a point(left,top), already scaled values, before i scale the view.

```
 How can i find this point? ->()------------------------
                               |    ______________     |
                               |    |            |     |
                               |    |   100x50   |     |
                               |    |            |     |
                               |    --------------     |
                               |                       |
                               -------------------------
```

Note : coordinate system as **[x : from left to right, y : from top to bottom]**

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate any point after a scale like so:

```
// find the position relative to the pivot point
float relativeX = pointBeforeScale.x - pivotPoint.x; 
float relativeY = pointBeforeScale.y - pivotPoint.y;

// multiply the relative position by the scale
relativeX *= scale;
relativeY *= scale;

// add the pivot point to the result to get the absolute position.
float pointAfterScaleX = relativeX + pivotPoint.x;
float pointAfterScaleY = relativeY + pivotPoint.y;
```

Comment: but pivot is center of view. why you don't scale him?

Comment: the pivot point does not move when scaling - that's the point of the pivot point - everything moves around it, but it stays in the same spot.